# Openlayers - ModifyFeature - How to label vertices with a progressive number

Tags: javascript, openlayers, labeling

Apologize in advance as I am quite new in openlayer and javascript.

I have a control ModifyFeature on a path vector layer.

I would like the vertices to be rendered with a stylemap label showing their progressive number (1,2,3,4,etc..), the same sequence they are stored within the linestring.

Any suggestion is very much appreciated.

Comment: You will need to hook into the featureModified callback, see, http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html which will receive the feature. You can then iterate through it's underlying point array and create labels on those vertices. That is the best way I can think of. I would be prepared to help you, but you need to put something up on jsFiddle as a starting point. Hope this helps.

Comment: ok, thanks John (sorry to be late in reply). I already did some tests with the callback with no result so far, but it is certainly due to my lack of knowledge. I will try more and if no success, then I will try to understand what you mean with jsFiddle. thanks again